# Reinstalling ubuntu without files

Tags: boot, login, system-installation

I had a rather difficult problem with ubuntu which was preventing me from logging in so I decided to reinstall it.Unfortunately, ubuntu only seems to allow me to "reinstall".
This installed all my files although the installation of previous programs failed.I then proceeded to boot up ubuntu and found that the problem persisted.

My question is, is there way was I can merely install ubuntu without retaining my files?

Comment: Doesn't it say down there at reinstall that it will keep your folder or stuff. If i'm wrong, check down there to find it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Are you saying that there is an option to simply reinstall ubuntu without retaining the files?

Comment: Yes, try checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

> Use the checkboxes to choose whether you’d like to Install Ubuntu
>   alongside another   operating system, **delete your existing operating
>   system and replace it with Ubuntu**, or — if you’re an advanced user —
>   choose the ’Something else’ option

See the screenshot below - its the middle option (it will say replace Ubuntu with Ubuntu in your case):

[image: It is the middle option on the screenshot]

Comment: Ah, sorry.I missed the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Burn bootable cd, or create bootable usb.
go to the bios and change boot order so your computer first boot cd or usb, then in installation window chose "something else" there you can format all your hard drives and install ubuntu.